# Continue the next step in a for... Next loop , only when the user click a button

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net , and I have this situation :

I have a button ( Mybutton1 ) .

I have also a sub that contains a for..next loop :

```
.....
for I=1 to nr1 
    {.... some instructions...}
   if condition1 then  
       Mybutton1.enable=true
       !!!!! at this point the loop must wait for the user to press the button !!!!!
   end if
Next
```

On every step of this For loop , the button became enabled when a condition is true , and in this case I want that this loop to stop until the user press the Button. ( the button's click event , at the end has some instructions that makes the button disabled again )

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Rather than breaking out of the for loop at every step when the condition is met, why not use a do or while loop?

Comment: but what I want is that the loop stop when a condition is true , and continue to the next step when the user press the button. How can I do this using a While loop ?

Comment: What you're describing is known as a coroutine. You want a method to yield execution until some other task completes (in this case, a button press) and then resume execution with its context/state as it was before. It's not trivial but certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

`Exit For` will break out of the for loop

```
.....
For I=1 To nr1 
    {.... some instructions...}
   If condition1 Then  
       Mybutton1.enable=true
       Exit For
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Ok , but if I go out the for loop , how can I go inside again when the user press the button ?

Comment: Actually the solution I was thinking of would not work so I removed it. I was thinking you could use an AutoResetEvent but since the form runs with a single thread it would block and freeze the entire form instead of what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to resume the loop after the user click the button, you can save the current value of the loop variable (`I` in your code) by declaring it as a class level field. The following code starts the loopwhen the user clicks Button1. It exits whenever `someCondition` evaluates to `True`. Each time the user clicks Button1, the loop continues from where it left off. If the user clicks Button1 after the loop has finished, an error message is displayed.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private number As Integer = 0
    Private lastNumber As Integer = 4

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If number >= lastNumber Then
            MessageBox.Show("Finished")
        End If
        Do While number < lastNumber
            number += 1
            Dim somecondition As Boolean
            'code that sets someCondition
            If somecondition Then Exit Sub
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry , but the for .. next loop should not be inside the button;s click event. This loop is inside another sub , and the button;s click event contains other code , that is executed not only within the for loop , but even in other occasions when the user click the button.

Comment: I just kept the code as simple as possible. You can move the code into a separate Sub. Just keep the same logic: the loop variable is declared at form level, the Sub exits when the condition is met, the Sub is called again when you want to resume processing.

Comment: I can't call the sub inside the button;s click event , because the button's click event is used in other situations that are not related with the loop.

Comment: @alex: What I'm saying is call it whenever you want to call it.

Comment: sorry , then I don't understand your idea. Can you modify your code to show your idea ? Thank you !